# Fabio and consul for microservices structure

Tags: microservices, consul

I'm trying to create a microservices architecture based on `consul` for discovery and `fabio` for load balancer.

Basically what I want to do is use consul to discovery some backend and frontend services and a database service.

I already have my services running and health checked so fabio can sees them but I'm trying to interact with them.

The main idea is use the consul DNS to establish a connection between front back and database and then expose the Fabio to balance the instances of each microservice.

In which case I have no idea on how to use consul's DNS to connect my back and database through Fabio so I can Balance my own microservices connection.

Comment: Eh? To use consul's dns just change any agents dns port to 53 and then you can use it normally. It's unrelated to fabio

Comment: I mean I want to use consul's DNS to connect my back and my db passing through fabio's load balance because I'm making multiple instances and/or another microservices to interact with each other. It's kind of odd. Basically consul to connect my microservices with each other and fabio to balance the load between them.

Comment: I never used fabio but from the document it appears fabio serves as HTTP and TCP gateway. If your microservices connect each other via consul DNS there would be no load balancing for the targets.

Comment: But fabio connects via consul's tags not via DNS as I understand so I'm looking for a way to create an interaction between consul and fabio for services discovery and connection from consul and load balancer from fabio

Comment: hmm I'm confused by what you intend to do. If you don't need load balancing for  database (which would be specialized), just use the services that require load balancing via fabio instead of consul.

Comment: Ok let's imagine I have a angular 6 front, a nodejs back and a postgresql DB. In order to connect Angular with Node I want to use consul's DNS and use Fabio to balance the load between my multiple instances of Nodejs and Postgres.
The problem is that I don't know how to use consul DNS for that, also don't know how connect Fabio with Postgres and use that to connect back and DB.

Comment: You could use fabio as the gateway to multiple node backend services. fabio shall serve as the web server/proxy which then connects to your backend depending on load. Your nodejs backend could connect to DB by their node name (the db servers also run consul agent), looked up via consul DNS. There would be no load balancing or fabio involved on that part.

Comment: So I can do a connection between angular and node trhough fabio's node name? If so then I can do the same to connect back and db right?

Comment: If you use fabio as the API/services gateway, it wouldn't need a node name or even joining the consul, it'd be the webserver for all services, or right behind the main web server for serving angular webpages. Since fabio supports TCP proxy in theory you could use it for db connection as well, but db load balancing or horizontal scaling requires a lot efforts more than that. Let say you do have 10 dbs properly set-up for load balancing, then you could add a fabio in front of them and let your nodejs connect to the fabio for load balanced db access.

Comment: Sounds great! I can connect Fabio with the front through Consul DNS so there's no need to use IP to connect?

Comment: You could if fabio node is registered with consul, but I dont see the point as it's supposed to reside outside of your backend group registered to consul. An ordinary set up would be more like this I think: clients => web server serving angular pages, fabio as gateway to services => [consul-managed: backend services, databases ]